# JQM Datebox remove Hours and Seconds from durationbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

I've had a good look through their docs, but does anyone know if it is possible to remove the 'days' and 'seconds' options from the popup for the durationbox?

Here is what I have:

```
<label for="time">Duration (mins)</label>
<input name="duration" id="duration" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "durationbox", "overrideDurationFormat": "%DM"}'>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yeah, something like:

```
"overrideDurationOrder":["h","i"]
```

I believe

Comment: That works, although you may have to replace all ' with " if you put this inside a data-options='...'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "durationbox", "durationOrder": ["d", "h"]}'>
```